# Magento 2 shopping Cart section call in cms page

Tags: cart, magento2.2.4

I want to  add the cart section on cms page using

Admin -> CMS -> Pages -> Select any page on which you want to display block -> Click on design tab from left navigation ->Under Page Layout section insert the code in "Layout Update XML" field.

But I don't know which section add into The Layout Update XML

Thanks in advance